# How to tag Docker images with a Git tag in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

Hopefully I'm just missing something simple, but I cannot figure out how to tag a Docker image with a Git tag in a Jenkins job.

I have been using the [Docker Build and Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Build+and+Publish+plugin) for building my images, but it's tag input only seems to accept token macros for input. The [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) doesn't export a tag macro and I haven't been able to find an alternative plugin that does. I had tried exporting the results of `git-describe` with the [Envinject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) into the environment but the Docker plugin doesn't seem to be able to read environment variables, even with the `${ENV,var=VARIABLE}` token macro.

I can achieve this by scripting the whole process, but I was hoping to use the Docker plugin for registry credentials management.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking another look at the problem with a clearer head, I found a simple solution to this problem in scripting the creation a temporary properties file with my git tag and using Envinject's "Inject environment variables" build step to read that file.

My final configuration looked somewhat like this: 
[image]